# How do I return a file download by a function?

Tags: python, function, file

Before the post I just wanted to premise 2 things:

1. I'm into programming from less than a month so any enhancement, alternatives, precisations or excesses in explanations, is **Boldy** appreciated.
2. It's my first post on Stack Overflow, hope I structured it correctly.

So I was trying to define a function "download(url)" that should download a file with a progress bar from a url given as whatever "url" is called in the function i just created.

I made it look like this:

```py
def download(url):
    import requests
    from progress.bar import Bar
    
    file = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    dictdata = eval(str(file.headers))
    total_length = dictdata["Content-Length"]
    with Bar("Downloading...") as bar:
        for chunk in file.iter_content(chunk_size=(int((int(total_length))/100))):
                <Here goes something that writes it down to a variable or something like 
                that but I don't know how that's called yet.> 
                bar.next()
    return <the variable or whatever it'll be.>
```

I expect it to work like this by the way:

```py
file = download(example)
```

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to store the `chunk` of bytes?

```
data = bytearray()
with Bar("Downloading...") as bar:
    for chunk in file.iter_content(chunk_size=(int((int(total_length))/100))):
        data += chunk
        bar.next()
return data
```

Comment: so when the function will be done I'll have a new variable data that contains the content of the file I want to download, right? Also I'm gonna be able to treat it always as a byte object if I got you, that sounds nice :)

Comment: my snippet is just part of the code, when the function is done it will `return` the data; you can name your variable anything you want, like this: `whatever = download('....')`